# Threejs: Make a panorama interactive with hotspots

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm trying to create a virtual tour using threejs using a 360 panoramic image, using the following example with my own panoramic image:

http://web.mit.edu/hawksley/Public/IntroToWebVR/demo/

Everything renders fine but I would like to make it much more interactive, that is to create hotspots.

Say, in the example above, if I add a hotspot icon and when I click it, it will go to another 360 panoramic image.

Any idea or help on how it could be done? Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js

Check this out. It has a vr player with hotspots inside.

Comment: This was very helpful , does it support gyroscope or deviceorientation feature? @mjanisz1